# C# to Python (not IronPython) Sending and Recieving Array's, Int, String, Decimals

Tags: c#, python, anaconda, xlwings, python.net

I have been researching a simple way to start a Python (not IronPython) script and pass parameters such as an Array, String, Int, Decimal and then retrieve an output such as an array from the Python script.

All research points to very complicated methods that are unreliable or IronPython which is limited.

If VBA can do this via xlwings (really well), why cant C# within Visual Studio?

Any advise, links or an example would be really helpful. Thank you

Comment: You can try pythonnet: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

Answer (score 0):

As @denfromufa mentioned, Pythonnet is the way to go. Here is how you can start a module and pass objects to it from C#.
Note:

- `numpy` is given here for example but you can replace it with any other module, even a custom one.
- an `array` object is showed as example but it is the exact same thing for `string`, `double`, `int`, etc.
- In this example I execute everything directly in the Python engine using `PyScope`, since your question was from C# to Python. If you need the object on the C# side, you can use `dynamic` types instead and import the module with `Py.Import()`.

```
using Python.Runtime;
double[] a = [2.1, 3.5, 5.4];

using (Py.GIL())
{
    using (PyScope scope = Py.CreateScope())
    {
        scope.Exec("import numpy as np");

        scope.Set("a", a.ToPython())

        scope.Exec("b = np.array(a)");
    }
}
```